# How to change the iOS Simulator SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can I change ios sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338957/how-can-i-change-ios-sdk)

Is there an other way to change the iOS simulator SDK as Hardware -> Version?

thanks for help.

**EDIT:**
finally I got it with applescript

```
set selectedVersion to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk"

set thePListFolderPath to path to preferences folder from user domain as string
set thePListPath to thePListFolderPath & "com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist"
tell application "System Events"
tell property list file thePListPath
tell contents
set value of property list item "currentSDKRoot" to selectedVersion
end tell
end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly sure what your desired out come is?

You can install other Simulators in Xcode Preferences:

[image: Xcode Preferences: Downloads]

If you would like to test your app on iOS 4.3 or 5.0, you will need to set your Deployment Target to the desired version. If you set your deployment target to 4.3, you'll be able to test with Simulator running iOS 4.3, 5.0 or 5.1.

Comment: i have installed all simulators and the deployment target is set to 4.3. I want to start my app with various simulator SDKs for some AutomatedTests.

Comment: Unfortunately you can only run one Simulator at a time.

Comment: i know. i want to change the simulator SDK between two jenkins tests and i have no idea what I can do

Comment: I think you're just able to run one test/Simulator at a time.

Answer (score 0):

yeah if you have installed the isd, then go to project/target and select the target with 3.0, all your simulators will be shown there and your application will be targetted to the desired version

to download sdk, go to xocde>downloadds